# "cannot get /" angular 2 error after adding Module app.module.ts in Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019 ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, typescript

"cannot get /" angular 2 error after adding Module app.module.ts in Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019 ASP.NET Core:

**app.module.ts**: =>

=======================================================================================

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';

**import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; // // Getting "cannot get /" error after adding this line. Else ASP.NET Core Angular Project loading properly.**

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    **NgbModule, // Getting "cannot get /" error after adding this line. Else ASP.NET Core Angular Project loading properly.**
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

==================================================================================================

Tried solutions given in below URLs but nothing helps:

1> [Angular2 / Cannot GET /page_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181218/angular2-cannot-get-page-name)

2> https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17625

Comment: Does your code compile?  What version of angular are you on?  There were issues in the past where I have needed to add styles to the styles section of the angular.json file for bootstrap.

Comment: Navigate to your ClientApp folder and run `ng build --prod` to see the error you have

Comment: I have fixed it by myself. The issue was with Microsoft Visual Studio - 'Package Manager Console'. When we install external NG package through Visual Studio - 'Package Manager Console' , it creates a 'node_modules' folder outside of 'ClientApp' folder.But the 'node_modules' folder is installed inside the 'ClientApp'  when we install through Angular CLI command window. Then, there are no errors while installing new external third party Modules. Anyway, thanks to Tony Ngo and Paul.